# JQuery, calling a form within an li

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of li's of which I am loading a small form into. Each li has a unique ID, but the form has the same class, because it is being called in to all of them. So, to select a single form, I would like to be able to call the form in a specific li, using the li's unique ID. So for example -

```
<li id="1"><form class="ourForm">...form data in here</form></li>
<li id="2"><form class="ourForm">...form data in here</form></li>
<li id="3"><form class="ourForm">...form data in here</form></li>
```

I would like to call .ourForm that's inside the li with the id of 2 (inside of a function). Is there a way in jquery to say "look for the form inside of the li with id of 2"? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: `div within a div` I don't see any divs here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that by using,

```
$('#2 form.ourForm')
```

or

```
$('#2').find('form.ourForm')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have numeric ids for li. You can try this:

```
$('li#2 form');
```

***FYI:***  prior to HTML5, ids cannot start with number. It is beeter practise to have non numeric ids. something like `li1, li2, li3, etc....`